# Given 4 points with 2 on different radius. Obtain the center of the circle

Tags: c, math

This is a problem on a programming judge.

In resume, the statement is the following :

> Black holes have an overwhelming gravity, such that the nearest stars begin spinning around them ([Example](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/483/195/original/UOJ_1783.png?1438189373)). Every affected star keeps constant angular velocity and distance from the black hole. Given 2 different positions of 2 stars in the black hole. Can you give the position of the black hole ?

The first line of input has the number **T** (1 ≤ T ≤ 10000) of test cases. Each test cases has 4 points (**X**,**Y**) (-1000.0 ≤ X, Y ≤ 1000.0) given in 4 lines; The old coordinate of the first star, the old coordinate of the second star, the new coordinate of the first star and the new coordinate of the second star respectively.

The output consist of a single line with the black hole coordinates.

Example of input:

> 3
>   12.00 2.00
>   5.00 6.00
>   10.00 8.00
>   2.00 7.00
>   0.50 -0.50
>   -1.00 0.00
>   -0.50 -0.50
>   0.00 1.00
>   0.50 6.50
>   -10.50 -3.50
>   -1.50 6.50
>   -5.50 -8.50

Example of output:

> 2.00 2.00
>   0.00 0.00
>   -0.50 1.50

My solution tries to find the point where the perpendicular bisector formed by the two stars positions intersect. The problem is that sometimes, the difference of the y coordinates of a star has 0 value, causing a division by 0 in my algorithm. There is other solution ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    double x,y;
}point_t;


int main(){
    point_t p1[2]; //p[0] is the old coordinate, p[1] is the new
    point_t p2[2];

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //slope , b for the 2 perpendicular bisectors
    double m1,m2,b1,b2;

    //auxiliar points to store values for the formulas
    double x,x0,y,y0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%lf %lf",&p1[0].x,&p1[0].y);
        scanf("%lf %lf",&p2[0].x,&p2[0].y);
        scanf("%lf %lf",&p1[1].x,&p1[1].y);
        scanf("%lf %lf",&p2[1].x,&p2[1].y);


        x0 = p1[0].x; 
        y0 = p1[0].y;
        x  = p1[1].x; 
        y  = p1[1].y;
        m1 = -((x-x0)/(y - y0)); // m = y - y0 / x - x0 >> bisector >>  m = x - x0 / y - y0

        x0 = p2[0].x; 
        y0 = p2[0].y;
        x  = p2[1].x; 
        y  = p2[1].y;
        m2 = - ((x-x0)/(y - y0));// m = y - y0 / x - x0 >> bisector >>  m = x - x0 / y - y0

        b1 = ((p1[0].y+p1[1].y)/2.0) - m1*((p1[0].x+p1[1].x)/2.0); // b = y - my >> x and y are the median points
        b2 = ((p2[0].y+p2[1].y)/2.0) - m2*((p2[0].x+p2[1].x)/2.0);// b = y - my >> x and y are the median points

        x = (b2-b1)/(m1 - m2);
        printf("%.2lf %.2lf\n",x, m1*x + b1);
    }
}
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to tag this as C, not C++.

Comment: The division by null error should be easy to avoid with a check, but if the solution mostly works and you want feedback on the design the this question might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: Your approach seems good to me. To avoid the asymptotic behaviour, I'd suggest you consider it from a vector perspective instead of a gradient perspective (e.g. the bisector has direction (-y,x) rather than gradient -y/x, and intersections can be found via this method: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-LineIntersection.html). You'll end up with an equivalent overall equation, but without the asymptotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a better representation for lines. Instead of using the point-slope form of a line, I suggest the `Ax + By + C = 0` form. You then find coefficients `A,B,C`. Note that they are only determined up to a factor; e.g., `2A,2B,2C` work just as well.

(One way to make the situation more definite if necessary is to only allow `C=1` or `C=0 and B=1` or `C=0 and B=0 and A=1`. But I don't think that's necessary for your problem.)

In this representation, all lines are on the same footing, so you don't have to set up special cases for vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as these, try getting "y - y0" kind of values to multiplication factor, rather than as divisor.
hope this helps.
Any more hint would be exact implementation of code, which I suppose you don't want ;)